# How to derive the way a controlled $U$ gate acts on an input state?

Tags: quantum-gate

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate#Controlled_(cX_cY_cZ)_gates) states that a controlled *U* gate maps the basis states to the following:

$$
  |00\rangle \mapsto |00\rangle\\
  |01\rangle \mapsto |01\rangle\\
  |10\rangle \mapsto |1 \rangle \otimes U |0 \rangle = |1 \rangle \otimes \left(u_{00}|0 \rangle + u_{10}|1 \rangle\right)\\ 
 |11\rangle \mapsto |1 \rangle \otimes U |1 \rangle = |1 \rangle \otimes \left(u_{01}|0 \rangle + x_{11} | 1 \rangle\right)$$

I am wondering how was this mapping derived?

I have looked at *Nielsen and Chuang - Quantum Computation and Information 10$^{th}$*; but I wasn't able to find the derivation process.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a derived mapping, it's the mathematical version of the definition of how a controlled gate works: it does nothing to the second qubit if the first qubit is $|0\rangle$, and applies the unitary $U$ to the second qubit if the first qubit is $|1\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :)